# sap.ui.getCore().createComponent fails with sapui5 version 1.72

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

We have 2 sapui5 Apps deployed onto Fiori launchpad. The parent app loads the child app using the **sap.ui.getCore().createComponent()** method.

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("com.test.childApp", "/childApp");

//Load the component
comp = sap.ui.getCore().createComponent({
                        name: "com.test.childApp",
                        url: "com.test.childApp",
                        id: 
                    });
```

The manifest.json file loads correctly for the child app when triggered from parent app on Fiori Launchpad version 1.44.40. We are in the process of updating our Fiori launchpad version to 1.72.20 and this bit of code is causing issues since the manifest file path comes back as 404 not found.

The URL for the manifest.json in the child App when trigerred from the parent app in v 1.72 ia as below:
**https://flpnwc-c910xxxxx.dispatcher.ap1.hana.ondemand.com/cloud/flp/3.113.1/com.test.childApp/manifest.json?ts=2.10.20**

while in 1.44, the URL for loading the manifest.json, the URL path was being resolved to:
**https://flpnwc-c910xxxxx.dispatcher.ap1.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fiori/parentapp/childApp/manifest.json**

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess your url should be `url: "/childApp"`rather than `url: "com.test.childApp"` and maybe you should try using `sap.ui.core.Component.create` rather than `sap.ui.getCore().createComponent`. Its also worth noting than registerModulePath is deprecated in favour of sap.ui.loader.config. You can read more on that [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.loader%23methods/sap.ui.loader.config)

Comment: Thanks Glen, will try these and get back with updates.